# How to take backup of Site prior to publish

Tags: msbuild, backup, teamcity, msdeploy, remote-server

I am using the following command to build package and deploy site on remote server using teamcity msbuild

```
/M /P:Configuration=%env.Configuration% /P:DeployOnBuild=True /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=%env.TargetServer%/MsDeployAgentService /P:DeployiisAppPath=%env.IISPath% /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /P:Username=%env.username% /P:Password=%env.password%
```

But I want to take a backup of that site to a particular directory. Tried doing this using batch file to compress and take a backup but it is a too much time consuming as it will run on a remote machine. I am looking for a solution that I can use using msbuild or any other that is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this document?

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups

It says that a backup is automatically created if it is enabled on the server (and then explains how to set it up)