# Copying files on remote server in TeamCity build step

Tags: ftp, teamcity

We would like our TeamCity build to backup the files on a remote web server before rolling out the new version. Pulling down the files via FTP and copying them on the build server is not a viable option due to the amount of files/file sizes. I'd like to copy them on the web server if possible.

Answer (score 0):

see [How to take backup of Site prior to publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410742/how-to-take-backup-of-site-prior-to-publish/17060544#17060544)

If you are using MSDeploy that can happen automatically.